# Finding anomalies in the product prices

Tags: sql, postgresql

I was given a SQL problem that has me stumped and was wondering if someone can shed some light on the best way to do this.

QUESTION:
Given the table "product_price" represents average price for a product for a period of time. All days from the range occur in the "day" column, which is NOT sorted.

| day | Price ($) |
| --- | --- |
| 4 | 2 |
| 5 | 1 |
| 3 | 1 |
| 1 | 1 |
| 2 | 5 |

Find anomalies in the product prices during this time period, more specifically find days when the price spiked (days on which the price was strictly larger than on the day before and the day after).

The first and last days can never be spikes.

EXPECTED OUTCOME: Output should be ordered in increasing order by "day"

| day |
| --- |
| 2 |
| 4 |

QUERY: I have tired this query

```
SELECT day FROM (
    SELECT
        day
        ,prev_price - price AS pre_diff
        ,price - next_price AS next_diff
    FROM (
        SELECT 
            day
            ,price
            ,LEAD(price) OVER(price) AS prev_price
            ,LAG(price) OVER(price) AS next_price
        FROM product_price
        ORDER BY day ASC
    ) a
) b
WHERE pre_diff > 1 and next_diff > 1
ORDER by day;
```

**UPDATE:** I think I solved it. Thanks @hsnsd for the tip. Would still appreciate any input if there is a better way to write this query.

```
SELECT day FROM (
    SELECT
        day
        ,price
        ,prev_price
        ,next_price
        ,price - prev_price AS pre_diff
        ,next_price - price AS next_diff
    FROM (
        SELECT 
            day
            ,price
            ,COALESCE(LAG(price) OVER(ORDER BY day ASC),0) AS prev_price
            ,COALESCE(LEAD(price) OVER(ORDER BY day ASC),0) AS next_price
        FROM prices
    ) a
) b
WHERE (day NOT IN (SELECT MIN(day) FROM  prices) AND
day NOT IN (SELECT MAX(day) FROM  prices))
AND (pre_diff > 0 AND  next_diff < 0)
ORDER BY "day";
```

[image]

Comment: Show us your attempts (queries), problems encountered and then we can help improve that. No one here will solve your homework or answer interview questions.

Comment: Hint: Use lead and lag to get the next day/previous day price.

Comment: The term "spike" carries a different meaning to "is different from" and you seem to be after the latter.

Comment: @Arvo apologies I hit submit before adding my query. Have added this to the question

Comment: Also value 1 in day 3 can be considered an anomaly as long as it differs from previous day value (5) and next day value (2). How do you handle that?

Comment: @Stu: Spike in this instance means that the days on either side were considerably lower price than the day that is considered a spike ie: day 2 price increased by 4 and then decreased by 4 on day 3

Comment: @lemon: First and last day can't be considered. Therefore day 1 is out. Day 3 is not considered a spike because the price decreased by 4 from day 2

Comment: @hsnsd: thanks for the tip. I think I have solved it. Have updated my post with the query that returned the desired outcome

Comment: Day 4 though only changes by 1, which is the least amount it can vary by, so how is that a "spike"? Is the threshold 1? If so any change is going to be a spike.

Comment: One option of determining if something is a spike or not is checking for the mode that in this case is 1 as it is repeated three times, or maybe the median. Would it be correct for you?

Comment: @Stu: agree that 1 wouldn't typically be considered a "spike". I think what the question was after is an increase in price seen from one day to another followed by a decrease. So if you picture a line graph you would see a "spike", even if it is a small one. How much it increased by seems irrelevant. Question could have been worded a better way. But this is what I had to work off myself.

Comment: I have added a query to the original post. Not sure if it's the best way to do this but it produces the desired outcome, ie: day 2 & 4.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like the following should give you the desired result:

```
with s as (
  select *, 
    Lag(Price, 1, Price) over(order by day) p,
    Lead(Price, 1, Price) over(order by day) n
  from prices
)
select day
from s
where p < Price and n < Price;
```

Comment: Thanks @Stu. Much refined version than my lines and lines of code. I'll have to read up more on LEAD/LAG